# Android Studio ConstraintLayout match vertically

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, android-constraintlayout

I'm making an app with a Navigatin Drawer Activity but in the content_main.xml it
puts an constraint layout, how can I remove/replace it or better make it match the height of the device?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Repalce it by linearlayout, you can change the constrainst layout tag to linear layout and make android:width="match_parent"